# How to step out of testing loop after one fail

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

How to exit loop test after one expect fail?

```
it('full range check sec should return reverse result', inject(function ($filter) {

      for(var i=0;i<100000;i+=60*50)
      {
        var result = $filter('sec2h')(i);
        var sign = result.substr(result.length-1);

        expect(sign).toEqual("h");

        var reversed_result = result.substr(0, result.length-1);
        reversed_result = reversed_result * 60 * 60;

        expect(reversed_result).toEqual(i);
      }
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may solve it on a higher level and let `jasmine` fail on a first fail with [`jasmine-fail-fast`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-fail-fast):

> Allow Jasmine tests to "fail-fast", exiting on the first failure
>   instead of running all tests no matter what. This can save a great
>   deal of time running slow, expensive tests, such as Protractor e2e
>   tests.